# TestFlight server error

Tags: testflight, ipad-mini

I have developed an iOS app by using the Titanium SDK. When I try to run it on the device using TestFlight, the app is unable to install on the iPad mini with iOS 6.0.2,
showing error:

```
This is testflight server error. Please try after sometime.
```

Can anyone tell me hat the actual problem is?

Comment: Did you try re-uploading the ipa file and trying again?  I've been using Testflight for a while now.  Other than some slow download speeds once in a great while, I haven't had issues with it.  I'm using it on IOS 5 and 6 devices.